# What is this title-less IME window that pops up periodically?

Tags: windows-7, ime

Periodically I get a window with no title that pops up on my Windows 7 Pro desktop, seen here with the menu it offers after I right-click on it:

[image]

It appears to be related to Unicode and IME.

What is this?  What are the likely ways I am making it pop up?  Do I want it? (I don't think so since I've never been able to make it do anything for me.)  How do I make it go away after it has popped up?

**Update:** I think it is browser-related.  My browser (chrome) just burped and appeared to reload most of its open tabs, and the mystery window is gone now.  I'd still like to know what the heck it is.

Comment: The handwriting input panel, perhaps? Do you use any tablets or digitisers?

Comment: No weird peripherals except a finger print reader that does nothing when I swipe it.

Comment: Google Desktop... but without a title?!

Comment: Google Desktop is not installed.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out what this is? I've currently got an instance on my screen.

Comment: @StarNamer not I, it definitely seems related to Chrome although I have not figured out which pages make it pop up.

Comment: I haven't noticed it for a few weeks, but shortly after I read your message if see it's back!

Answer (score 1):

To find out, run Process Hacker (see: [Process Hacker downloads](http://processhacker.sf.net/downloads.php), ignore banner add, choose "Installer).  Place rodent (mouse) cursor over the "Find Window" icon (just to the right of the "System Information" button), hold mouse button, then move mouse over the window you're wondering about, and release mouse button.  See which process is selected by Process Hacker.

Alternate process: If you have Process Explorer installed, and have agreed to its EULA, go to File menu, and choose "Show Details for all processes".  Then perform a similar dragging action with the "Find window's process" icon, which is just to the right of the binoculars icon.  Process Explorer may be obtained from [TechNet: Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx).

(The programs are rather similar, with Process Explorer being more well known due to its primary distributor.  Process Hacker's home page mentions some of its advantages over Process Explorer.)